# read from file with a delimiter

Tags: java, file-io

i want to know how can i read from file in java until the file pointer arrives at a `delimiter` or `specific number` of  characters.

in `c++` i used from `getline()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use BufferedReader.readLine(), or maybe the Scanner class.

Comment: how can i do that with scanner class?

Comment: @mehdi: [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)